# Springer Bibliographystyle: References in paper text too long and without brackets

Tags: bibliographies, natbib, sv-classes

I have to write a paper with Springer Bibliographystyle.

I do `\cite{khan2013}` and receive this in the text:

> Khan, Muhammad Naeem Ahmed and Khalid, Muhammad and ul Haq, Sami (2013),

That is definitely too long.

In my references I see following which is no problem:

> Khan, Muhammad Naeem Ahmed and Khalid, Muhammad
>   and ul Haq, Sami (2013) Review of requirements management issues in software development. International Journal of Modern Education and Computer Science 5(1):21

I would like the following outcome in the text:

> [Khan 2013]

```
\documentclass[twocolumn, natbib]{svjour3}
\smartqed
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{natbib}


\begin{document}
\bibliographystyle{bise}
\bibliography{bibname}

\end{document}
```

@Oleg: There is a template from the editor Springer. I pasted here in the following

```
\begin{filecontents*}{example.eps}

gsave
newpath
20 20 moveto
20 220 lineto
220 220 lineto
220 20 lineto
closepath
2 setlinewidth
gsave
.4 setgray fill
grestore
stroke
grestore
\end{filecontents*}
```

%
    \RequirePackage{fix-cm}
    \documentclass[twocolumn, natbib]{svjour3}          % twocolumn
%\documentclass[smallextended, natbib]{svjour3}

%
    \smartqed  % flush right qed marks, e.g. at end of proof
%
    \usepackage{graphicx}
    \usepackage{natbib}

```
\begin{document}

\title{Insert your title here%\thanks{Grants or other notes
```

%about the article that should go on the front page should be
%placed here. General acknowledgments should be placed at the end of the article.}
    }
    \subtitle{Do you have a subtitle?\ If so, write it here}

%\titlerunning{Short form of title}        % if too long for running head

```
\author{First Author         \and
    Second Author %etc.
}
```

%\authorrunning{Short form of author list} % if too long for running head

```
\institute{F. Author \at
          first address \\
          Tel.: +123-45-678910\\
          Fax: +123-45-678910\\
          \email{fauthor@example.com}           %  \\
```

%             \emph{Present address:} of F. Author  %  if needed
           \and
           S. Author \at
              second address
    }

```
\date{Received: date / Accepted: date}
```

% The correct dates will be entered by the editor

```
\maketitle

\begin{abstract}
%Insert your abstract here. Include keywords, PACS and mathematical
%subject classification numbers as needed.
\keywords{First keyword \and Second keyword \and More}
% \PACS{PACS code1 \and PACS code2 \and more}
% \subclass{MSC code1 \and MSC code2 \and more}
\end{abstract}

\section{Introduction}
\label{intro}
2018 Your text comes here. Separate text sections with Your text comes here.         Separate text sections with Your text comes here. Separate text sections withYour text comes here. Separate text sections withYour text comes here. Separate text sections withYour text comes here. Separate text sections withYour text comes here. Separate text sections withYour text comes here. Separate text sections withYour text comes here. Separate text sections withYour text comes here. Separate text sections withYour text comes here. Separate text sections withYour text comes here. Separate text sections withYour text comes here. Separate text sections with.\\
```

relevant design problems.\

```
\noindent\hspace*{5mm} %With its focus on the de \\
```

Your text comes here. Separate text sections with
    \section{Section title}
    \label{sec:1}
    Text with citations \cite{alt2018} and \cite{balzert2009} and \cite{rogers2016}             and \cite{mendez2017}.
    \subsection{Subsection title}
    \label{sec:2}
    as required. Don't forget to give each section and subsection a unique label         (see Sect.~\ref{sec:1}).
    \paragraph{Paragraph headings} Use paragraph headings as needed.
    \begin{equation}
    a^2+b^2=c^2
    \end{equation}

```
\begin{figure*}
% Use the relevant command to insert your figure file.
% For example, with the graphicx package use
\includegraphics[width=0.75\textwidth]{example.eps}
% figure caption is below the figure
\caption{Please write your figure caption here}
\label{fig:2}       % Give a unique label
\end{figure*}
```

%
% For tables use
    \begin{table}
% table caption is above the table
    \caption{Please write your table caption here}
    \label{tab:1}       % Give a unique label
% For LaTeX tables use
    \begin{tabular}{lll}
    \hline\noalign{\smallskip}
    first & second & third  \
    \noalign{\smallskip}\hline\noalign{\smallskip}
    number & number & number \
    number & number & number \
    \noalign{\smallskip}\hline
    \end{tabular}
    \end{table}

```
\bibliographystyle{bise}      % Bise style is numbered
\bibliography{bibtex_libname}   % name your BibTeX data base



\end{document}
% end of file template.tex
```

Comment: Could you please provide a usable bibtex entry to the offending paper? It would also be good to have a link to the style. It seems that bibtex is confused about what of the names are surnames, by the way.

Comment: Please post the raw bib entry in question, *not* just the way it gets formatted by BibTeX.

Comment: I'm going to guess that the author field of the entry in question currently is as follows: `author = "{Khan, Muhammad Naeem Ahmed and Khalid, Muhammad and ul Haq, Sami}",`. If this guess is correct, you must remove the offending pair of curly braces and re-run BibTeX, followed by two more LaTeX runs. The citation call-out should then say `Khan et al`, not just `Khan`.

Comment: @Oleg, thank you for your reply. In addition there is the Springer template

Comment: @Mico you were right I just deleted the curly braces. Perfect tks. But I want Khan et al (2013) in brackets like that [Khan et al, (2013)]. Can you help again?

Comment: @maxmin - Is something stopping you from writing `[\citet{khan2013}]`?

Comment: @Mico thank you, everything is like I wished now.